# CLI editor in heroku?

Tags: heroku, editor, command-line-interface

I've seen other questions of this, but they all seem to be at least 2 years old, and Heroku seems to have changed things so that those answers don't work.

I'd like to be able to use an editor (preferably emacs, but I'm not picky at this point) directly on my ruby projects as they live on heroku. There doesn't seem to be an emacs or vim or anything in the bash shell, and none of the plugins I've found have worked. none of the add-ons that Heroku offers appear to be text editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a [buildpack](https://github.com/technomancy/heroku-buildpack-emacs) do to this.
Buildpacks are shell scripts executed when your app is deployed. They will allow you to install packages on your app and have those available at runtime.

However, build is the only moment where you can edit those files. Any file edited at runtime will not be updated on the running dynos in your app.
This is because each dyno is a separate container (Heroku is using LXC. But it's the same technology as Docker). So editing the files within your app will edit the currently running container, not the other ones.

Comment: so, an editor to edit my app directly on Heroku needs to be PART of my app? That seems weird. So I need to add it to the git repo that holds my app?

Comment: oh, so I can't actually edit running ruby files and have it actually do anything? That's disappointing...

Comment: Also, how do I actually RUN the buildpack? I have installed the vim buildpack, but I can't figure out how to use it, and documentaiton seems hard to find...

Comment: Running the buildpack happens automatically on deploy. No, you shouldn't make that "part" of your app. You should edit the files locally and trigger a new deploy (a GIT push).

Comment: See also https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: ok, so I can edit the fires in the current run, but they won't last. That's fine I'm only using this for debugging on my testing dyno anyway... AH, and I figured out: heroku vim doesn't work, but heroku run vim does!

Comment: The emacs buildpack seems to be dead (archived) but the vim one seems to work. Are there any other editors other than vim?  I only  find vim...